# Printing numpy array as a member of pythonlist

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was experimenting with numpy arrays, I had this very simple example:

```
list = [2, 3]
list.append(np.array([3.2, 9.0, 7.6]))
```

And if I do `print(list)`, it prints: `[2, 3, array([3.2, 9. , 7.6])]`

But if I do `print(list[-1])`, it prints only `[3.2 9.  7.6]`
Can anyone expalin this for me, that if I print the numpy array as the last element of my python list, why does it print without the "array", the brackets, and the comas between the numbers?
Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects in python generally have two different methods that return a string representation of themselves for `print`.

They are `__str__()` and `__repr__()`, and they have different uses that you can read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr).

To print something you first have to convert it to a string. Normally `print` will attempt to use `__str__` to make this conversion.

Doing `print` on a list results in a call on `list.__str__()`, which then tries to convert all it's internal elements into a string for printing. The call the list uses to convert these elements is `__repr__()`.

So when you `print` a `list`, the `list` gets the `__repr__` of each element, but when you print just that element, the `print` gets the `__str__` of that element.

What you're seeing is the difference between `__repr__` and `__str__` in a `numpy` array.

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
x.__str__()
x.__repr__()
```

Output:

```
'[1 2 3]'
'array([1, 2, 3])'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because a numpy array when it's printed looks like a list.

But try this:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> l = [2, 3]
>>> l.append(np.array([3.2, 9.0, 7.6]))
>>> isinstance(l[-1], list)
False
>>> l2 = [3, 2]
>>> isinstance(l2, list)
True
```

And you will test that the array is not actually a list.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is because `print` function implicitly calls `__str__` on its args.

But if you embedd an object in a list, to represent what is in the list, `__repr__` will be call for all elements inside the list:

```
a = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)
print(a)
# [ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10.]
print(repr(a))
# array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.])
```

what you can do is cast the array to a list when printing and the `array` won't show up:

```
print([a])  # not good
# array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.])
print([list(a)])  # better
# [[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]]
```